# Evaluating the usefulness of creating a use case diagram after completing MVP in academia

Tags: architecture, uml, software-design, use-case, use-case-diagram

I just completed a minimum viable product (MVP) version of my game as part of my university project. I am unsure whether if I should also make a section with the UML use case diagrams in the thesis **at this late stage**. I am asking because unlike an industrial project where the use case should be in the business modelling, elaboration or, and especially when modelling the system requirement, to understand the design requirements of the system, here I am not in a mockup or requirement gathering stage, which is long past and completed during the project proposal stage. Here I have a working prototype that is in the stage of being an MVP.
Would it be wise for me to add it at this stage for an academic paper?
I have researched into UML use cases and discovered that they could be prepared during reverse  engineering, in the case where   use  cases are  used   to   prepare   the   requirement details from the existing application. However I am not sure whether I am in the stage of reverse engineering yet.

Answer (score 1):

Simply spoken: it depends. In your case I would just talk to the tutor, professor or which ever person is caring for you and ask for the need of it. Then decide what to do.

In any case I would at least sketch the  use cases so in order to show that you got the idea of it (which I hope you have). There is probably no need to go into a detailed UC description for each UC. Again, to make an example you should detail a single UC in a way that you describe the scenario. Finally you should also show the collaboration for a single UC.

While writing the above I was thinking about the goal of your work (**your** UC that is). If it has a focus on UML then you need to do a lot of detail work. Else, go to the top of my answer.

Comment: just to be clear, by "collaboration for a single UC", did you mean building an additional UML collaboration diagram  in addition to a use case diagram?

Comment: Well, yes. That's why you start the fuzz with UCs: to get the collaboration with your class design.